# Complex string replace - multiple files, multiple different strings, must include certain text

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, xml

I have a number of XML files (Atlassian Confluence space exports FYI), that I need to parse through to replace certain strings, as long as the line begins with a set string.

Here is an example of a line that I need to parse and change:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira" ac:schema-version="1" ac:macro-id="4dacac64-1234-8dd4-badd-acdfddf208d4"><ac:parameter ac:name="server">Jira Server Name</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="columns">key,summary,assignee,reporter,status</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="maximumIssues">20</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="jqlQuery">project = SOMECODE and issuetype = IssueType and &quot;SomeOtherThing&quot; != ExtraThing </ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="serverId">6adef236-9999-66a6-72bc-e87a4cc03c47</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro>
```

The two things that I need to replace are the values of:

- `<ac:parameter ac:name="serverId">`
- `<ac:parameter ac:name="server">`

All lines that need to have values replaced start with:

`<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira"`

There are multiple different values of "serverId" and "server", that will need to be matched and replacced.

I have tried to use `sed` with regex, but can't work out how to add regex like:
`(.*?)`, to grab all the different values of 'serverId' and 'server'.

These two lines of sed are the closest I've got, but once again, I need to be able to 'fuzzy match' the server value (ie. 'Jira Server Name'), and the server Id value (ie. 6adef236-9999-66a6-72bc-e87a4cc03c47)

- `sed -i -e '/<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira"/s~\(<ac:parameter ac:name="server">\)Jira Server Name\(</ac:parameter>\)~\1Replacement Server Name\2~' entities.xml`
- `sed -i -e '/<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira"/s~\(<ac:parameter ac:name="serverId">\)6adef236-9999-66a6-72bc-e87a4cc03c47\(</ac:parameter>\)~\16c3d2a6e-1234-95cb-33f3-b11a8ff01c44\2~' entities.xml`

How can I 'wildcard' the serverID and server name values in my sed commands, so that I can match and replace multiple different ids/names?

Is `sed` the right tool for the job? Is there another/easier way to do this?

---

Actual XML file to be considered:

```
<jira>
<object class="BodyContent" package="com.atlassian.confluence.core">
<id name="id">12334762</id>
<property name="body"><![CDATA[<h1>Links</h1><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira" ac:schema-version="1" ac:macro-id="a0d29f31-1212-4234-abcd-9ba23456f8cf"><ac:parameter ac:name="server">JIRA SERVER NAME</ac:parameter>6123450c-1234-acdb-8123-33333397828b</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="key">ABC-272</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p><h1>Files</h1><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name="attachments" ac:schema-version="1" ac:macro-id="4f911234-1234-1234-1234-12345aad9b77" /></p>]]></property>
<property name="content" class="Page" package="com.atlassian.confluence.pages"><id name="id">443449761</id>
</property>
<property name="bodyType">2</property>
</object>
<object class="OutgoingLink" package="com.atlassian.confluence.links">
<id name="id">931112345</id>
<property name="destinationPageTitle"><![CDATA[some thing]]></property>
<property name="lowerDestinationPageTitle"><![CDATA[some thing]]></property>
<property name="destinationSpaceKey"><![CDATA[https]]></property>
<property name="lowerDestinationSpaceKey"><![CDATA[https]]></property>
<property name="sourceContent" class="Page" package="com.atlassian.confluence.pages"><id name="id">943325975</id>
</property>
<property name="creator" class="ConfluenceUserImpl" package="com.atlassian.confluence.user"><id name="key"><![CDATA[1234567890]]></id>
</property>
<property name="creationDate">2018-10-10 07:02:45.817</property>
<property name="lastModifier" class="ConfluenceUserImpl" package="com.atlassian.confluence.user"><id name="key"><![CDATA[1234567890]]></id>
</property>
<property name="lastModificationDate">2018-10-10 07:02:45.817</property>
</object>
<object class="Page" package="com.atlassian.confluence.pages">
<id name="id">123457845</id>
<property name="hibernateVersion">10</property>
<property name="title"><![CDATA[20170428 - somehing]]></property>
<property name="lowerTitle"><![CDATA[20170428 - somehing]]></property>
<collection name="bodyContents" class="java.util.Collection"><element class="BodyContent" package="com.atlassian.confluence.core"><id name="id">1234567</id>
</element>
</collection>
<collection name="contentProperties" class="java.util.Collection"><element class="ContentProperty" package="com.atlassian.confluence.content"><id name="id">1234567</id>
</element>
<element class="ContentProperty" package="com.atlassian.confluence.content"><id name="id">123456748</id>
</element>
<element class="ContentProperty" package="com.atlassian.confluence.content"><id name="id">123456749</id>
</element>
<element class="ContentProperty" package="com.atlassian.confluence.content"><id name="id">123456750</id>
</element>
<element class="ContentProperty" package="com.atlassian.confluence.content"><id name="id">123456751</id>
</element>
</collection>
<property name="version">1</property>
<property name="creator" class="ConfluenceUserImpl" package="com.atlassian.confluence.user"><id name="key"><![CDATA[1234567890]]></id>
</property>
<property name="creationDate">2018-09-20 04:52:30.727</property>
<property name="lastModifier" class="ConfluenceUserImpl" package="com.atlassian.confluence.user"><id name="key"><![CDATA[1234567890]]></id>
</property>
<property name="lastModificationDate">2018-09-20 04:57:08.072</property>
<property name="versionComment"><![CDATA[]]></property>
<property name="originalVersion" class="Page" package="com.atlassian.confluence.pages"><id name="id">878936102</id>
</property>
<property name="originalVersionId">878936102</property>
<property name="contentStatus"><![CDATA[current]]></property>
<property name="position">2143289343</property>
</object>
<object class="BodyContent" package="com.atlassian.confluence.core">
<id name="id">443449754</id>
<property name="body"><![CDATA[<h1>Links</h1><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira" ac:schema-version="1" ac:macro-id="a0d29f31-acdb-1234-1234-12345ffff8cf"><ac:parameter ac:name="server">JIRA SERVER NAME</ac:parameter>6123450c-1234-acdb-8123-33333397828b</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="key">ABC-272</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p><h1>Files</h1><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name="attachments" ac:schema-version="1" ac:macro-id="abcd1236-1234-1234-1234-abcd3aa12345" /></p>]]></property>
<property name="content" class="Page" package="com.atlassian.confluence.pages"><id name="id">443613611</id>
</property>
<property name="bodyType">2</property>
</object>
</jira>
```

Comment: (1) I tried your sample command with your sample data, and it worked fine (with sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2).  Please show the error you get, and state what version of `sed` you’re running.  (2) Part of your problem is that `sed` doesn’t support non-greedy regular expressions (``*?``).  (3) Can you possibly rework your problem into something with shorter strings, to make the question more manageable?  (4) Please give a clearer statement of your objective.  Do you have lists of old and new values for server name and serverID?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  You say “there are multiple different serverIds and server values”, “I can't work out how to match different server IDs and values”, and “How can I wildcard the serverID and server name values, so that I can replace multiple different servernames/IDs with a single one?” I don’t understand what you mean. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Hi @G-Man, I've edited the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Also @G-Man, I think you hit the nail on the head - I'm wanting to do something like
 (2) Part of your problem is that sed doesn’t support non-greedy regular expressions (*?). Is there another/better tool for the job?

Comment: Yes: `xmlstarlet`. I'll try to get you an example later today. In the meantime please can you post a slightly larger block of the XML. Do feel free to remove large or sensitive textual content, but leave the tags as best you can.

Comment: Hi @roaima, this is a pastebin with some XML example:
https://pastebin.com/CB9WFK9r

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that's not valid XML. You're missing the outermost element, and possibly some xmlns namespace declarations. Temporarily I've added `<jira>` surrounding it.

Comment: Arrgghh. The `CDATA` section in which you're really interested also isn't valid XML - you've got too many `</ac:parameter>` element closes. Did you mangle it when you substituted `JIRA SERVER NAME`?

Comment: I hope not! The original example should work:
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira" ac:schema-version="1" ac:macro-id="4dacac64-1234-8dd4-badd-acdfddf208d4"><ac:parameter ac:name="server">Jira Server Name</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="columns">key,summary,assignee,reporter,status</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="maximumIssues">20</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="jqlQuery">project = SOMECODE and issuetype = IssueType and &quot;SomeOtherThing&quot; != ExtraThing </ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="serverId">6adef236-9999-66a6-72bc-e87a4cc03c47</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro>

Comment: the file starts with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-generic datetime="2019-04-14 06:04:43">

Comment: That's almost entirely useless in a comment. Please [edit] your question and fix the broken XML directly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, simply make sure to use a pattern that fits only the name or the id. As the fields include everything upto the next opening `<`, this should be simple:

```
sed -i -e '/<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira"/s~\(<ac:parameter ac:name="server">\)[^<]*\(</ac:parameter>\)~\1Replacement Server Name\2~' entities.xml
```

with `[^<]*` matching all characters except for `<`.

Please note that this will only work for input like this. Theoretically, xml files may contain line breaks or other stuff that will break any script that is not aware of xml syntax. Then better use something like a python script with `import xml.etree.ElementTree`

Comment: I'll give it a shot! Thanks for that!